# Xcode Forcing Swift Optional Unwraps Twice (!!)

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am subclassing a UIStoryboardSegue and every time I try to use one of the two UIViews, Xcode is making me add two optional unwraps (!!) such as:

```
let sourceView = self.sourceViewController.view
sourceView!!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight
```

or

```
let sourceView = self.sourceViewController.view!
sourceView!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight
```

or

```
self.sourceViewController.view!!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight
```

I'm wondering if someone could explain why this is.

Comment: Xcode is a double-edged sword.  It has trouble recognizing the types used in functions every now and since it is an implicitly typed language.

Comment: @Garret actually it's not XCode but the compiler framework which has those flaws. And we will likely have to live with that for quite a while

Answer (score 7):

The `sourceViewController` property of `UIStoryboardSegue` is typed as `AnyObject`, and as an Objective-C compatibility feature, once you `import Foundation`, things get a little weird with `AnyObject`.

Instead of looking for methods on the `AnyObject` type, Swift looks for Objective-C selectors instead, exactly as Objective-C does with the `id` type. Any selector from any class is fair game: if you wanted, you could try to invoke `activeProcessorCount` on your object, even though that's a `NSProcessInfo` selector, and the compiler would let you do it. (It would fail at runtime for obvious reasons.) This is called dynamic dispatch, in opposition to static dispatch (the normal calling mechanism in Swift).

One thing about dynamic dispatch, though, is that it always adds a layer of implicit wrapping. If you have an Objective-C property that returns a `String`, dynamic dispatch will have it return a `String!`.

Things get hairy when multiple classes declare selectors with the same name but different return types (or with different parameters, but we're not interested in this case here). I don't know how the compiler chooses which selector out of the many identically-named ones it knows about. Either way, it picks one, and you're stuck with it unless you cast the object to a more precise type, in which case the Swift compiler will only let you use static dispatch.

Using `swiftc`'s `-dump-ast` argument, we can see a lisp-like representation of how the compiler parsed the expression:

```
(pattern_binding_decl
  (pattern_named type='UIView?!' 'sourceView')
  (dynamic_member_ref_expr type='UIView?!' location=MySegue.swift:15:46 range=[MySegue.swift:15:25 - line:15:46] decl=UIKit.(file).UIGestureRecognizer.view
    (member_ref_expr type='AnyObject' location=MySegue.swift:15:25 range=[MySegue.swift:15:25 - line:15:25] decl=UIKit.(file).UIStoryboardSegue.sourceViewController
      (derived_to_base_expr implicit type='UIStoryboardSegue' location=MySegue.swift:15:20 range=[MySegue.swift:15:20 - line:15:20]
        (declref_expr type='Segue' location=MySegue.swift:15:20 range=[MySegue.swift:15:20 - line:15:20] decl=xxx.(file).Segue.func decl.self@MySegue.swift:14:7 specialized=no)))))
```

There's a lot of cruft, but you can see that it generated a `dynamic_member_ref_expr` instead of a `member_ref_expr`. If you scroll all the way to the right to the `decl` "attribute", you'll see that it is using `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `view` property ([declared as `UIView?`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view)), so that the expression returns a `UIView?!`.

In contrast, `UIViewController`'s `view` property is declared as `UIView!`. If the compiler picked this selector instead, you would have ended up with a `UIView!!`, and you would need only one level of explicit unwrapping.

You can (and must, in instances like this one) explicitly unwrap implicitly-unwrapped values. With `sourceView` as a `UIView?!`, the first `!` unwraps the `UIView?!` into `UIView?`, and the second one unwraps the `UIView?` into a finally usable `UIView`. This is why you need two exclamation marks.

The class that declares the selector used for dynamic dispatch is irrelevant, as long as the target object implements it, accepts compatible arguments, and returns a compatible type. `UIView?` and `UIView!` are compatible at the binary level, so in the end, your program still runs. However, if you were somehow expecting a `String` or another unrelated type, you could be in for a surprise. In my opinion, you should avoid dynamic dispatch as much as you can.

**tl;dr**: if you cast `sourceViewController` to `UIViewController`, you get the correct `view` property definition and won't need to unwrap it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!! Love knowing more than just what's on the surface

Answer (score 2):

`self.sourceViewController.view` is a rare case of a "double-wrapped Optional":

- once because UIStoryboardSegue's `sourceViewController` is typed as an AnyObject - to which the `view` message can be sent, because type-checking is suppressed, but at the cost of getting back an Optional (as I explain my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECsuppressing)
- and again because a UIViewController might or might not *have* a view - indeed, a UIViewController's `view` is initially `nil`, until the view loads and `viewDidLoad` is called - so the `view` property is itself typed as an Optional

Thus we wind up with an Optional wrapped in an Optional. What I do, in this situation, is write it like this in Swift 1.1 or before:

```
let sourceView = (self.sourceViewController as UIViewController).view
```

Or with `as!` in Swift 1.2:

```
let sourceView = (self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController).view
```

The downcast settles all doubts at once. Now, setting `sourceView.frame` just works.

Comment: `UIViewController`'s `view` property is not optional.

Comment: The point I was trying to bring is that the type is `UIView?!` because Swift selected a `view` selector for dynamic dispatch that returns a `UIView?`, instead of `UIViewController`'s own `view`, which is not optional. Additionally, `sourceViewController` is not optional either.

Comment: @zneak Actually UIViewController's `view` property _is_ optional.

Comment: You are correct. It is implicitly-unwrapped, though.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
self.sourceViewController.view
```

return kind of `UIView?!`
You have to unwarp twice to get UIView. First unwarp `!` then unwarp `?`

```
    let test:UIView?! = nil
    let firstunwrap = test! //Here kind of firstwrap is UIView?,so need second wrap
    let seconunwrap = firstunwrap!
```

If you got a kind of `UIView!?`,

you only need to unwarp once.because `!` is `implicitly unwrapped optional`

```
    let test:UIView!? = nil
    let firstunwrap = test!//Here firstwrap is UIView!,do not need to wrap anymore
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more? For instance, in which case might be beneficial to use `?!` and in which case, the other - `!?`? (<- this is an actual question mark :-)

Comment: To be honest, I never design my code to user ?! or !?, I will cast it to special class as early as possible.